# Why does the download page recommend the previous version?

Tags: 8

Why does Drupal download page recommend Drupal 7.x? I can hardly see the footprint about Drupal 8.

Does it mean Drupal 8 is still under development? Does it mean Drupal 7.x can be the last stable version?

Comment: 8 is not released yet. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal

Comment: Please put your comment as Answer! I want to make it as the answer of the question for other users to use your information :)

Comment: @Ehsan We don't really need this question to be answered, it'll go out of date and won't be useful in future.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the availability of Drupal 8 at a specific point in time

Comment: I was just thinking maybe it's good for the Drupal newcomers. You're right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Drupal is under development. See
 http://drupal.org/core/release-cycle

API freeze was in July, now API completion phase.